# Make a batch file log off the current user after a certain period of inactivity

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, logout

I would like to make a batch file where after a certain time of inactivity on the logged on user, it will log it out (not shut down the computer, or log anyone else out, just log out the active user).

I am not an Admin on my user, so I cannot to anything Admins can do, but if I am able to do SOMETHING to allow me to achieve this, please tell me. Please do not give me links, I have explored Microsoft websites, and many forums, I have viewed pretty much everything, but there's only ones that shutdown your whole computer.

Comment: `shutdown /L` does a logoff.

Answer (score -1):

Without admin rights you can't change the built in policy and a batch file cannot monitor mouse movement and keyboard movements in other program windows.

However you can set the screensaver to require your password and make your screensaver fire up after 2 minutes inactivity etc.

Without admin rights you cannot control any user features other than your own user.